# How to conditional format a cell when the time in the cell is 15 minutes past the hour?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, time, conditional-formatting

I've been tasked with creating a spreadsheet that organizes and visualizes employee productivity. One specific request was that I create a formula that will highlight cells on two columns that contain employee clock-in and clock-out times.

I want to do a conditional format that will highlight the cell in light red if the employees clock-in time is 15 minutes past the hour it occurred.

For example, highlight the cell if the time is 07:18, or 09:22, because they are both 15 minutes past the hour the clock-in occurred.

Unfortunately, I cannot provide the spreadsheet as it contains sensitive employee data. Hopefully, this is adequate information to get my questions across clearly.

I first begun by using greater than or less than statements but quickly realized that wouldn't necessarily work because employees on the list clock-in and out for their shifts at different times. If they all were required to clock-in at the same time, it would make this astronomically easier.

I now know it must be a conditional format using formula, however, I'm not the greatest when it comes to excel formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`MINUTE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/minute-function-af728df0-05c4-4b07-9eed-a84801a60589). Assuming your timestamp is in `A1`:

```
=MINUTE(A1)>15
```

Comment: The timestamps are sorted in column C. I would like for this conditional format to apply to all cells within column C as I will continue to add employee timestamps in this format.

Comment: Then apply the rule to the entire column or some sufficiently large portion of it.